# Proof that group is not cyclic

Tags: group-theory

Equation $z^{12}=e$,where e is identity element, has $14$ solutions in group $G$.Proof,that $G$ is not cyclic.

As I know, such an equation has a solution $z = e^{(ik\pi)/(6)}$ , where $
k \in {0,...,11}$ , but where we can get 2 other solutions.The thing is to proof that those two solutions can't be represented as $e^{(ik\pi)/(6)}$ like.Have no idea how to proof that.

Comment: You used complex numbers in a group that may contain those.

Comment: If the group in question is $(\Bbb C\setminus\{0\},\cdot)$, then your attempt makes sense but in general, it doesn't.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas Okay,wrong guess. So is it solvable in circumstances presented.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: show that a cyclic group has precisely one subgroup of each order which divides the order of the group.

Use this to count the number of elements of orders which are factors of $12$.

Derive a contradiction.